# jira rest expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency

Tags: java, rest, jira

I am developing rest plugin for jira atlassian and I have this kind of problem.
every time I want that my apis are showing up I need to add empty constructor to my new api in this format

```java
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/import-issues")
public class ImportIssuesRestResource {
    private ImportIssuesAction importIssuesAction;

    public ImportIssuesRestResource() {
    }

    public ImportIssuesRestResource(final ImportIssuesAction importIssuesAction) {
        this.importIssuesAction = importIssuesAction;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("issueNumber")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getFields() {
        return Response.ok().entity(importIssuesAction.getIssueNumber()).build();
    }
}
```

However what I want is something like this

```
@Scanned
@Path("/import-issues")
public class ImportIssuesRestResource{
    private ImportIssuesAction importIssuesAction;

    @Inject
    public ImportIssuesRestResource(final ImportIssuesAction importIssuesAction) {
        this.importIssuesAction = importIssuesAction;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("issueNumber")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getFields() {
        return Response.ok().entity(importIssuesAction.getIssueNumber()).build();
    }
}
```

with injected constructor and @Scanned. I get this error when I am using the second version of code.

```
 Error creating bean with name 'rest.ImportIssuesRestResource': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [action.ImportIssuesAction] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

The others api have similar injected constructor and using annotations @Scanned or @Named. I need my api real-time getting information from class. However currently I am getting NullPointerException in rest of my public getter getIssueNumber. I am using @Named in class ImportIssuesAction.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like ImportIssuesAction has not been declared as a componentimport in your atlassian-plugin.xml
https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/Components-injection-with-Spring-Scanner/qaq-p/553801

Comment: As I know is deprecated using componentimport, instead of is recommended to use @Scanned annotation, which I used